# Laravel Query Builder Query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I want to make a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM batches WHERE id = 20 AND status = 3 OR status = 8
```

I tried following query but it returning me all records with `status = 8`

```
Batch::where('id', 20)->where('status','3')->orwhere('status','8');
```

What mistake did I make?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`whereIn`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses)

```
Batch::where('id', 20)->whereIn('status', [3,8]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Advanced Wheres](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres)

```
 Batch::where('id', 20)->where(function($query) use ($staus){
       foreach($status as $stat){
           $query->orWhere('status','=',$stat);
       }
 })->get();
```

Comment: PHP methods and functions are case insensitive.